# xna Loading content from a non GameComponent class

Tags: c#, xna

I am a relative beginner in XNA and am trying to create a `screenManager` for an C# XNA game. Everything in my code seems to work fine until I reach the `LoadContent` method in my `MainMenu` class which derives from `Screen` which is a custom standalone class. This is where I get my `GraphicsDevice` component not found `ContentLoad` exception.

This is on the the statement: `texture = c.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/Start");`
where c is a `ContentManager`.

This statement and the program works okay if I put it in the Update method of my class. However, I only want to load this texture once, not with each call to `Update(GameTime)`. I think I must be calling load before some Content info is being initialized but I'm not sure what. There are some commented out statements in `MainMenu.LoadContent` that do pretty much the same thing and all produce the same error. I'm posting my entire code here. Hope it isn't flooding the forum. 
Here's Game1.cs:

```
namespace RoomGame
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        public static GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        GameController gameController;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

            gameController = new GameController(this,this.Content);
            this.Components.Add(gameController);
        }

    }
}
```

GameController.cs:

```
namespace RoomGame
{
    public class GameController : DrawableGameComponent
    {
        public Game game;
        public ContentManager content;
        public ScreenController screenController;
        public MainMenu menu;
        public GameController(Game game,ContentManager c)
            : base(game)
        {
            this.game = game;
            content = c;
            screenController = new ScreenController(this);
            menu = new MainMenu(this,this.content);
            screenController.AddScreen(menu);
        }

        public override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();
            screenController.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            base.LoadContent();
        }

        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            base.UnloadContent();
        }

        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            screenController.Update(gameTime);
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            base.Draw(gameTime);
            screenController.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

screenController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace RoomGame
{

    public class ScreenController
    {
        public List<Screen> screens = new List<Screen>();
        GameController gameController;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        public ScreenController(GameController gc)
        {
            this.gameController = gc;
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {

            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(this.gameController.GraphicsDevice);
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            foreach (Screen screen in screens)
            {
                if (screen.isUpdating)
                    screen.Update(gameTime);
            }
        }

        public void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            foreach (Screen screen in screens)
            {
                if (screen.isDrawn)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Begin();
                    screen.Draw(gameTime,spriteBatch);
                    spriteBatch.End();
                }
            }
        }

        public void AddScreen(Screen screen)
        {
            if (!screens.Contains(screen))
            {
                screen.LoadContent(this.gameController.game.Content);
                screens.Add(screen);
                //screen.Initialize();

            }
        }




    }
}
```

Screen.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;

namespace RoomGame
{
    public class Screen
    {
        public ScreenController screenController;
        public bool isUpdating=true;
        public bool isDrawn=true;
        public GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;

        /*public Screen(ScreenController sc)
        {
            this.screenController = sc;
            this.isActive = true;
        }*/

        public virtual void Initialize()
        { }

        public virtual void LoadContent(ContentManager c)
        { }


        public virtual void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        { }

        public virtual void Draw(GameTime gameTime,SpriteBatch sb)
        { }
    }
}
```

MainMenu.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;

namespace RoomGame
{
    public class MainMenu : Screen
    {
        GameController gameController;
        Texture2D texture;
        Vector2 position;
        ContentManager content;
        //public GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;

        public MainMenu(GameController gc,ContentManager c)
        {
            this.gameController = gc;
            this.content = c;
            this.isUpdating = true;
            this.isDrawn = true;
            //this.graphics = this.gameController.game.graphics;
        }

        public override void LoadContent(ContentManager c)
        {

            texture = c.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/Start");
            //texture = this.gameController.game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/Start");
            //texture=this.gameController.content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/Start");
            //texture = this.gameController.Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/Start");
        }


        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            //texture = this.gameController.content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/Start");
            position = new Vector2(100, 100);
        }

        public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime,SpriteBatch sb)
        {
            sb.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance....

**EDIT**
I found my error. I was calling `ScreenController.Add` before the `LoadContent` in `GameController`. I put it after the `base.LoadContent` in `gameController` and it works now. I hope this can help somebody but if anyone know a better way of approaching this please let me know.

Comment: Please, don't post all of your code next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `MainMenu.LoadContent` from the constructor of the `ScreenController` which in turn is called by the `Game's` constructor. `LoadContent` should be called at the appropriate time. So move the call to `AddScreen` to the `LoadContent` method of the `GameController`.